# How can I get useful data from lists in a list?

Tags: python, algorithm, list

Maybe the question is not very clear. Here is the example. 
I have a list, data structure like this:

```
[[221.86797965649234, 490], [306.5453090728297, 400], [307.3621570649666, 842]]
```

How can I use a efficient method to get a new list, that is [490,400,842]?

Currently, my method is

```
List = [[221.86797965649234, 490], [306.5453090728297, 400], [307.3621570649666, 842]]
newList = []
for n in List:
    newList.append(n[1])
```

If the original list has over million items, it would be very slow. Is there any efficient method?

Comment: Building a list is a linear time operation. Which means building a million element lists will be million of times slower then building a singleton list. Live with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> List = [[221.86797965649234, 490], [306.5453090728297, 400], [307.3621570649666, 842]]
>>> [l[1] for l in List]
[490, 400, 842]
```

If your list has over a million items and performance as measured actually becomes a problem, you may want to look at storing it in a database or using some other approach that lets you control access to it more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension:

```
>>> myList = [[221.86797965649234, 490], [306.5453090728297, 400], [307.3621570649666, 842]]
>>> [x[1] for x in myList]
[490, 400, 842]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want always the last item then you can use:

```
>>> list
[[221.86797965649234, 490], [306.5453090728297, 400], [307.3621570649666, 842]]
>>> [x[-1] for x in list]
[490, 400, 842]
```

Answer (score 0):

try a list generator :

```
newListGen = (item[1] for item it List)
```

this has the advantage that the data item is only generated once the item is requested.

The bigger question is where did you get your original million long list from, and what do you need to do with it - it may well be that there are better data structures to use for such a massive data set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
newList = [n[1] for n in List]
```

On a side note, try not to capitalize variable names. For example, `list` is better than `List`. But, try also not to use names that already mean something in Python. So, `list` isn't a great name.

[PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) is a good style guideline to follow.